# What is the 2-legged oauth scope described as "Download PDFs and arbitrary files"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-drive-api

The "Download PDFs and Arbitrary Files" scope name would seem to refer to downloading any non-native google file types, but I can't find any more information about it.  I am able to use the documents list API doc feed entry to obtain a download link, which usually works, but I have recently encountered some unexpected auth failures while attempting to download which led me to discover this additional application manifest oauth scope.

The defined scopes are described [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/manifest#supported_scopes) and another list (which omits the "download" scope) [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/oauth#TokenScope).  What is this scope and where can I find more information about it?

**EDIT**

I am using various google data APIs within the context of google app engine, and it is the app engine instance manifest which is declaring its required scopes.  Since different scope lists are documented differently depending on the contexts in which the google data APIs are being used, and I am referring to the documentation for an app engine application manifest, I am including the app engine tag.

**EDIT**

The scope is additionally mentioned (by URL - https://docs.googleusercontent.com/) in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files), and would seem to be required in order encompass all potential download sources.

Comment: Why is it tagged "google-app-engine"?

Comment: Because it applies to the 2-legged oauth scopes defined for app engine applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did some quick testing and it seems that the scope `https://docs.google.com/feeds/` gives you access to the Document List API itself (listing files, reading and writing metadata) while `https://docs.googleusercontent.com/` allows you to download non-native Google Docs formats so files such as PDF, images etc... that have been uploaded by the user to Drive. To me it seems that `https://docs.googleusercontent.com/feeds/download/` is an alias to `https://docs.googleusercontent.com/`

Comment: What method did you use to download the non-native files?

Comment: You have to use the URL in the <content> tag and use an authorized request to access it (using OAuth 2.0 for instance). For instance for one of the images in my drive:
 <content type='image/jpeg' src='https://doc-10-3c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/1q2we34r5t6y7u8/qwertyui/1339660800000/098765432123456/098765432/12345678&amp;e=download&amp;gd=true'/>

Comment: Downloading directly from content.src does not require the googleusercontent.com scope.  There is an API specifically for downloading to a local file, which I thought googleusercontent might apply to, but I haven't looked at what the corresponding client library does internally (which may very well simply be reading from content.src).

Comment: Note that I'm speaking from the context of 2LO scopes defined via app engine application manifest, not requesting scopes via 3LO.  The latter may very well behave differently.